# Displaying Empty List message in Detail Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, master-detail

I currently have an Activity that has two layouts depending on whether the device is a phone or a tablet. My Activity has one boolean mTwoPane that keeps track of the layout. On the phone, it works exactly as I want, if the list is empty on initial launch of the listfragment view, I use the SetEmptyText to set my "The list is empty!" message. However, on the tablet, this message is only displayed on the list fragment in the left, and I would like to have it displayed in the Details fragment instead.

Is it possible when it tablet mode with ListFragment and DetailFragment side by side that if the ListFragment has no data, the empty message is displayed in the DetailFragment instead?

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjCQ5.png for tablet and https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRAgl.png for mobile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you could use is to add a TextView containing the error message in the detail fragment and filling the fragment view. If your list is empty you can show it otherwise you set its visibility to gone and display the details view.

A second approach would be to create a Fragment especially for showing that the list is empty and choose the fragment to display based on your list content.

Comment: Thanks! Using the TextView that I can disable seems to be the approach.